# How to add/merge dataframes in a list

Tags: r, merge

I used the following for loop to read 7 csv files and add them to a list.

```
list <- list()
l <- 1
for(i in 1:7){
      data <- read.csv(paste("file",i,".csv",sep=""),header=FALSE) 
      list[[l]] <- data 
      l <- l + 1
}
```

So now I have a list named "list" containing 7 dataframes, right?

Each of the 8 dataframes contain the same three columns (NAME, SURNAME, AGE).
I now want to add:

```
df <- dataframe(NAME,SURNAME,AGE) ## to each dataframe in the list.
```

Did that help at all? My question is, how can I achieve that for all 7 objects in the list automatically!

Comment: Try providing a working source code example.

Comment: From reading again, I understand that you initially created a list of length 8.  7 csv files were read into the 7 elements of the list and later the 8th list element was updated with the 8th dataset.  Now, you want to rbind the 7 datasets each with 8th element in the list?

Comment: exactly!! I am new here, should explain better next time! Below, I posted an answer with more details!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 'lst' has seven data.frames and want to 'rbind' the 8th dataset to each of the datasets in the list, we can use `Map`

```
 Map(rbind, lst, list(d1))
```

Or using `lapply`

```
lapply(lst, rbind, d1)
```

#### Update

If the 'lst' is of length 8, and wants to rbind the first 7 elements with the dataset in the 8th element, then you can just do

```
 Map(rbind, lst[-8], lst[8])
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
lst <- lapply(1:7, function(i) as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, 3*10, 
         replace=TRUE), ncol=3)))

set.seed(49)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 3*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if the ultimate goal is to just ensure all 8 CSV files make it into one data.frame:

```
# generate some sample files
files <- sprintf("iris%d.csv", i)

for (i in 1:8) { write.csv(iris, files, row.names=FALSE) }

# make one happy data frame
do.call(rbind, lapply(files, read.csv))
```